# Use of Reflection With object Class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an API In Which I am receiving object of custom class

```
    [HttpPost("[action]")]
    public ResultSet AddApplication([FromBody] Application model)
    {
     // Code Here
    }
```

Application is a custom class and have around 64 properties .

Now Instead of Application object , I want to receive it as

```
    public ResultSet AddApplication([FromBody] object model)
```

Before Proceeding any further I want to check wether there are 64 key in 
"object model" or not

I can do that with Reflection on class

```
     Type T = typeof(LoanApplication);
     PropertyInfo[] P = T.GetProperties();
```

But how to check keys in an object Type ?

I want something like

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public ResultSet AddApplication([FromBody] object model)
{
 Type T = typeof(model);
 PropertyInfo[] P = T.GetProperties();
}
```

But here typeof(model) give error because its a variable , cant use it like a Type.

I need this in case if source send wrong data (less property or property name mismatched) than I should be able to find out what is wrong by comparing properties of My Custom Type and received object

So is there any way to get keys from object model in a list (with or without reflection)??

**Update 1 :**

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public ResultSet AddApplication([FromBody] Application model)
{
 // Code Here
}
```

If API receive wrong model than in above code  model will be null (in debugging) and it means we will never know what went wrong, which property is mismatched or not present in received object

But

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public ResultSet AddApplication([FromBody] object model)
{
}
```

Here if model is wrong than still it will be received as object and by getting array or list of its property I can compare it with my custom type

That allow me to get every information of what went wrong , this response i want to send back so that user of this API so they will know what mistake they made

Ex : -

[image]

Comment: **Why** do you want to do this.  [This **is** an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).

Comment: because if source send wrong data (less property or property name mismatched) than I should be able to find out what is wrong by comparing properties of My Custom Type and received object

Comment: Good Question by the way

Comment: So for debugging or logging?  I say this because this isn't the place to really do either.

Comment: Dear Erik , No . Please Check Update 1 . I tried to explain More

Comment: You still haven't explained it because what are you going to do with the data????? LOG it??? I mean you can't just view the data live all the time...

Comment: Just curious, what runtime type you are expected to create from arbitrary data sent by client? Best I can think of is to use dynamic and hope it works for you.

Comment: I guess this is not the right way of doing it. If your purpose is to validate the input data that you can do it directly. For e.g. as you mentioned in case if the the input sent is misspelled a particular property, it will not be assigned to the object during 'parameter binding', all you have to do is check/validate the individual fields of your object for valid values.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen , Please check Update 1 and suggest me what should I try

Comment: @Thangadurai - exactly I want to do what you mentioned  "check/validate the individual fields of your object for valid values"

Comment: I see your update1, in this case you can define your own model binding class where you have the option of validating its values before binding. Since you have not tagged any asp.net versions, i assume it is asp.net core. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) is the msdn reference for custom model binders.

Answer (score 1):

So as I mentioned in my comment, changing your *good path* to account for bad data is an extremely poor choice.  Your *good path* should do it's job as if everything is normal.  If you want to *catch* requests with invalid data then use an ActionFilter:

```
public LogInvalidDataRequstFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(ActinExecutingContext filterContext)
  {
    if (!filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      // Data isn't valid so now what?
    }
  }
}

[LogInvalidDataRequestFilter]
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public ResultSet AddApplication([FromBody] Application model)
{
 // Code Here
}
```

Comment: Thanks , But again this approach will only work in case of Data annotation validation , Not in the case I mentioned here . If user send Mismatched property than in actionfilter too it will received as null and will make "ModelState.IsValid" useless code

Comment: If the property is null, and it has `[Required]` then it's not valid...

Comment: Please check snapshot in Update 1 , ModelState.IsValid Does not provide any info in that case

Comment: So I'm done with this question since you apparently don't understand what's happening here.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a Lot , Very Helpful